# Show Daywise records from start_date to end_date

Tags: php, database, date

I want to show the records from database daywise from start dat to end date...the records has date which is inserted to the database at the record insertion time...the records are not stored daily so there must be a gap between two dates record. So now I want to show the records daywise that is if the perticular date has no records i want to show 0 instead of it.

I am able to show the records which date is stored in database. But cant show the records which date are not available in the database.

```
>$res=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate");
>while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
>{
>  $date[] .= $row['Date'];
>}
>
>foreach($date as $da)
>{
>  $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Date = '".$da."' ";
>  $result = mysql_query($query);
>  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
>  {
>   $prod = $row['No_of_prod'];
>  }
>  echo $prod;      
>}
```

Comment: can you share the SQL query or code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you put empty entry each day in database and fetch it  OR
In php code you create an array with key as dates starting from start date till it reaches to end date and value to it will be zero(0). After fetching database record you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
function and then final array generated can be used to display data. On your request for creating date range following is the code

```
$dt_start = new DateTime('20090101');
$dt_end   = new DateTime('20090222');
$arrDates[] = $dt_start->format('M');
while ($dt_start->modify('1 day') <= $dt_end) {
    $arrDates[$dt_start->format('Y-m-d')] = 0;  // Or whatever you want to do with it.
}
```

`$arrDates` contains dates range.

Comment: check out date range code. put dates as per your code in `yymmdd` format. avoid zeroth array value